# JAVA - JTextArea has a fake visual location after translate its parent graphics

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, jtextarea

I'm trying to create a canvas(`JPanel`) that can have text Boxes(`JTextArea`) on it and I can also drag the canvas or the text boxes around. Now the dragging text boxes functions are ok. I can use `setBounds()` to set the location for the `JTextArea`.

However, when it comes to dragging the canvas, problems come. I use `Graphics2D.transform` to move the canvas. After the canvas is moving, there will be a visual text area and a hidden real text area. I have reset the bounds of `JTextArea` to fit the moving offset of the canvas but it doesn't work.

Below is an example,

[image: the GIF of the problem]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

/**
 * @author Zhijie Lan<p>
 * create date: 2020/11/25<p>
 **/
public class TranslateJPanel extends JFrame
{
    public TranslateJPanel() throws HeadlessException
    {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        add(canvas,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setSize(1280, 720);     
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                               
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TranslateJPanel();
    }
}

class Canvas extends JPanel
{
    private final JTextArea jTextArea;
    private int offset = 0;

    public Canvas()
    {
        setLayout(null);

        jTextArea = new JTextArea("hello!!!!!!!!!!!");

        jTextArea.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
        jTextArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        add(jTextArea);

        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
            {
                super.mouseDragged(e);
                offset++;
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });

        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                System.out.println("M: "+ e.getX()+"  "+e.getY());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate(offset, offset);
        g2.transform(at);

        jTextArea.setBounds(offset,offset,100,100);

        System.out.println(offset);
        System.out.println(jTextArea.getX()+"      "+jTextArea.getY());
        System.out.println("***************************");

    }
}
```

Comment: This does not look good, safe or correct. For one thing setting position of components within a painting method is dangerous in the extreme and will likely have many untoward side effects.

Comment: Note that you should never set the size of a text component, especially a JTextArea, and in fact you should never set the preferred size of these guys since this will mess up the areas ability to expand as necessary as more text is added. Most often you'll set its column and row properties and then display it within a JTextArea.

Comment: In fact, why are you overriding paintComponent at all? And offset doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you're trying to move the text area, wouldn't you want to put the mouse listener on the text area and not the panel. If it's on the panel, then the mouse could be anywhere on the panel (not on text area) and the text area would move.

Comment: 1) Don't call you class Canvas. There is an AWT component by that name which get confusing. 2) I second all of @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter, comments 3) See [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) for a basic listener that will allow you to drag any component. You would not drag the panel, only the components added to the panel. So you would all the listener to all components you add to the panel, not the panel itself.

Comment: Please, setting the layoutManager to null is just asking for problems. LayoutManager's make like easier for programmers.

Comment: @NomadMaker, you need a null layout for dragging of components. Since the component will be dragged to random locations a layout manager can't know what the location should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following for draggable text areas:

1. Do not override paintComponent or any painting method, don't use AffineTransforms or anything that moves pixels around. Instead move the components themselves.
2. This might be one of the few times that I might use a null layout. Note that there are layout managers that can be used in its place (and I think Camickr has written code for this and may be able to give you a link to this).
3. Never set the size of the JTextArea or even its preferred size.
4. Instead, set the column and row properties.
5. Add the JTextArea to a JScrollPane (to its viewport actually)
6. Add a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener to the JScrollPane that moves it
7. Add a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener to the JTextArea that forwards mouse actions to the JScrollPane that holds it, but be sure to change the MouseEvent's source property to reflect the JScrollPane, not the JTextArea.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DraggingBoxesPanel extends JPanel {
    public DraggingBoxesPanel() {
        int w = 900;
        int h = 600;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));

        setLayout(null); // I usually avoid doing this
        add(createTextBox()); // add first "box" to this JPanel
    }

    // exposed method to allow adding a new "box" to GUI
    public void newBox() {
        add(createTextBox());
        revalidate(); // The JScrollPane requires this
        repaint();
    }

    private JComponent createTextBox() {
        int rows = 10; // jtextarea property
        int cols = 20; // jtextarea property

        // create text area and scroll pane
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(rows, cols);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        // let scrollpane size itself
        scrollPane.setSize(scrollPane.getPreferredSize());

        // scrollpane's mouse listeners
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        scrollPane.addMouseListener(myMouse);
        scrollPane.addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);

        // mouse adapter that forwards mouse actions in
        // text area into its containing scrollpane
        MouseAdapter textAreaMouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // make sure source is correct
                e.setSource(scrollPane);
                myMouse.mouseReleased(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                e.setSource(scrollPane);
                myMouse.mousePressed(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                e.setSource(scrollPane);
                myMouse.mouseDragged(e);
            }
        };

        textArea.addMouseListener(textAreaMouseAdapter);
        textArea.addMouseMotionListener(textAreaMouseAdapter);

        return scrollPane;
    }

    // code that allows a component to be dragged
    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private Point mousePt1;
        private Point compPt1;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mousePt1 = e.getLocationOnScreen();
            Component comp = (Component) e.getSource();
            compPt1 = comp.getLocation();
            
            Container container = comp.getParent();
            container.setComponentZOrder(comp, 0);
            container.revalidate();
            container.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (mousePt1 == null) {
                return;
            }
            dragComponent(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            dragComponent(e);
            mousePt1 = null;
        }

        private void dragComponent(MouseEvent e) {
            Point mousePt2 = e.getLocationOnScreen();
            int x = compPt1.x + mousePt2.x - mousePt1.x;
            int y = compPt1.y + mousePt2.y - mousePt1.y;
            Component comp = (Component) e.getSource();
            comp.setLocation(x, y);
            
            Container container = comp.getParent();
            container.revalidate();
            container.repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        final DraggingBoxesPanel mainPanel = new DraggingBoxesPanel();
        JButton newBoxBtn = new JButton("New Box");
        newBoxBtn.addActionListener(e -> mainPanel.newBox());
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(newBoxBtn);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DraggingBoxesPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution to this problem.

In the `void paintComponent(Graphics g)`,
instead of

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
```

using

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
```

Solve the problem, but don't know why.

I'm new in JAVA, so I cannot deeply understand all the warnings from everyone's advice, but thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: It's still not a good or safe solution. You don't want to use painting as a solution for a component placement problem, and again, you never want to change component state from within a painting method.

Comment: What you're doing here is creating a new Graphics object and making changes to it. The reason that this helps is because you're not corrupting the Graphics object given to you by the JVM and which is used in painting of child components and borders. If you do create your own Graphics object in this way, be sure to dispose of it when done. Corollarily, never dispose of the Graphics object given to you by the JVM (passed into your paintComponent method).

Comment: This is NOT a solution. A painting method is for painting only. It should NOT change the state of any property or of any other component.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter Yeah, yours is better. And one more thing, why never set the size of the JTextArea? I already created a kind of text box that can be resized by mouse like the ones in the PowerPoint, and it seems fine.

Comment: @ZLan: JTextAreas are meant to re-size, to get larger, if the text they complains is larger than the bounds of the current text area display. Thus they are also scrollable, if displayed within a JScrollPane (as they should be), then scrollbars automatically appear if the text area's text exceeds its bounds. If you set the size of the preferred size, you ruin this functionality. Do an experiment: run my code and add a bunch of text to one or more of the text areas, and you'll see automatic display of scroll bars. then try with your code to see what happens.